# Why iptables drop all packets?

Tags: debian, security, iptables

I set this role for drop invalid packets:

```
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP
```

but it drop all packets.
this is all my iptables rules:
[image: iptables]

Comment: Maybe you did something else too? can you provide *everything*? `iptables-save -c` . Keep -c, it can help find what happens.

Comment: That would have been as text, not screenshot...

Comment: I know you have an answer, but it would be best to post the raw iptables text as code in the question. Screenshots of readable text are hard to read.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because you chose to mark **ALL** TCP first connection packets (those with a SYN flag) as *NOTRACK*, means your connections can never have a proper conntrack state, and all packets after the first get the *INVALID* state, which you drop.

- first TCP packet, with SYN flag, is marked as *UNTRACKED* in *raw* table,
- following TCP packets, cannot be *NEW* because they don't have a SYN flag. They cannot be in *ESTABLISHED* state either because *ESTABLISHED* follows *NEW* (not to mention the actual important meaning: that there would have been a conntrack entry created before, but it wasn't here, so no valid entry can be found). So their state becomes *INVALID*,
- your new rule `-A PREROUTING -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP` drops *INVALID* state: all TCP traffic is dropped in the end (except the first SYN), which gets probably a lot of `SYN_RECV` when checking with `netstat -tn` or `ss -tn`.

Advice: redo completely your rules from scratch, because you don't appear to master the effect of them and you didn't explain why or how you got them. *conntrack* is supposed to take charge of all the states and flags of TCP, but you still have at least 13 rules checking these states. Then you're using matches like *conntrack* or *connlimit* which rely on Netfilter's *conntrack* to work properly. Either don't use *conntrack* anymore at all (including: don't use *connlimit*, don't check *conntrack*'s state anymore, like *NEW*, *INVALID* ...) in any rule, or remove all those incompatible rules.

Comment: Interesting, @AB... would you mind having a look at this question over at serverfault: https://serverfault.com/questions/1051798/iptables-rules-blocking-all-inbound-traffic , it seems you may be able to throw some light on it, thanks for any advice...